# Apply table() function to same column name in multiple dataframes - r

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply the table() function to the same column in several data frames. I'm sure there is a more efficient way than just typing each line of code and changing out the data frame.. This is what I've been doing.. *(data frames are abram, arlington, blanche, carson, diamond; column name is Admin_Supp)*

```
table(abram$Admin_Supp)
table(arlington$Admin_Supp)
table(blanche$Admin_Supp)
table(carson$Admin_Supp)
table(diamond$Admin_Supp)
```

I tried to play with lapply() but I couldn't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated ~ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place the extracted columns from the datasets in a `list` and apply `table` by looping over the `list` with `lapply`

```
lapply(list(abram$Admin_Supp, arlington$Admin_Supp, blanche$Admin_Supp, 
  carson$Admin_Supp, diamond$Admin_Supp), table)
```

---

Or place the datasets in the `list`, extract the column by looping and apply `table`

```
lapply(list(abram, arlington, blanche, carson, diamond), function(x)
           table(x$Admin_Supp))
```

---

If we are interested only in `data.frame` objects created in the global env, we could also loop over the environment and extract the column only if it is data.frame

```
Filter(length, eapply(environment(), \(x) 
   if(is.data.frame(x)) table(x$Admin_Supp)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if there is a way for me to extract the same column from all the datasets without having to type it out after each data frame name? (i.e. I would like to just indicate which column once... not sure it possible) thanks again ~

Comment: @CatherineTiczon You could place those dataset in the list, extract by looping (as in the update)